# ConcurrentMap.compute used as remove

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

With Java 8, I am implementing a wrapper on `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap` interface, particularly the `remove(Object key)` method. Since I need to do more checks during the remove, I need to implement the functionality using

`compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction)`

However, here the problem is: I have to accept `Object` but pass that to `compute` as `K`. With generics, I even can't do a runtime check like `if (key instanceof K) ...`

I understand why the signature for `compute` was chosen this way; if it was just `Object`, in case that compute needs to create a new entry, it could not simply use the key. But I am not sure how to resolve this - is there any recommended pattern but use multiple calls as below?

```
for (;;) {
    V v = map.get();
    if (check(k, v)) {
        if (map.remove(k, v)) return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *"I even can't do a runtime check like if (key instanceof K) ..."*, you can, but you will have to store `Class<K>` as a type-token in your wrapper instance.

Comment: You can safely cast because erasures strip the type information and a Map only uses the `Object` methods of a key. Its ugly, but safe and acceptable practice.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at default implementation of `ConcurrentMap.compute` it seems that you can safely use an unchecked cast assuming that your `remappingFunction` can handle the `Object` not of type `K` and return `null`. So you can use:

```
public V remove(Object key) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    V result = compute((K)key, (k, v) -> {
        if(v == null) return null;
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

The `compute` implementation first uses `get(key)` (which accepts any object, thus it's safe), and passes the result to the `remappingFunction`. If the key has invalid type then result will be `null`, so your `remappingFunction` should also return `null`. In this case the `containsKey(key)` will be called which also accepts any object and will return `false` for invalid object and `compute` will return `null`.

Note that the behavior of the [`ConcurretMap.compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) is well-documented (even the equivalent code is provided), so it's unlikely that such implementation will break in future.

Comment: `ConcurrentMap.compute` is just the default implementation, optimized collections are very likely to implement that directly, without calling get etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea which came into my mind was to use `containsKey` to pre-check whether the map can handle the particular key object. If this method returns `true`, the map can handle it, thus an unchecked cast to `K` would be ok.

But…

```
ConcurrentMap<String,Integer> map=new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
map.put("foo", 42);
map.containsKey(0);
```

is already enough to prove that despite the fact that the method `containsKey` has `Object` as parameter type, it will not necessarily work with arbitrary argument types— in this case it throws a `ClassCastException`.

That said, even your original loop using `get(Object)` and `remove(Object,Object)` is not guaranteed to work.

Without an additional type token, there is only one type safe way to do it:

```
return map.entrySet().removeIf(e ->
    Objects.equals(key, e.getKey()) && check(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

but besides the performance of a linear search there is the theoretical possibility that it removes the key more than once if a concurrent insertion of the same key happens during the traversal.

---

So the only solution for being both, atomic and type safe, is to resort to a runtime type token (i.e. usually initialized via a class literal):

```
ConcurrentMap<K, V> map;
Class<K> keyType;

public boolean remove(Object key) {
    if(!keyType.isInstance(key)) return false;
    K k=keyType.cast(key);
    for(;;) {
        V v=map.get(k);
        if(v==null || !check(k,v)) return false;
        if(map.remove(k, v)) return true;
    }
}
```

Note that you can use something like

```
if(keyType.isInstance(key))
    map.computeIfPresent(keyType.cast(key), (k,v) -> check(k, v)? null: v);
```

to atomically remove the mapping, if present and the `check` succeeds, but you can’t use it to return whether the removal actually happened as the `compute…` methods make no difference between keys that were not present and keys which were removed as in both cases, `null` will be returned.

Comment: The ClassCastException (haven't tested this myself) is rather a bug of ConcurrentSkipListMap since it does not adhere to its contract. And returning false in case that key is not instance of key type would generally break the contract, since this does not take types into account, just `equals()` results.

Comment: [`Map.containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-): “**Throws**:
*`ClassCastException` - if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map ([optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions))*” The `ConcurrentMap` does not modify this contract. If a type based pre-check doesn’t solve your problem, there is no type safe solution at all. Of course, you may catch the `ClassCastException`…

Comment: Right, haven't spotted this part in the documentation. Thanks, though the desired solution does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use forEach method of Map and put that into forEach

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> 
System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```